# Intellimouse Optical-side buttons for Catalina

Tags: homebrew, mouse, macos

[image]

My ~20 year old Intellimouse Optical optical functions in Catalina.  I would like to be able to use the side-buttons to "go-back" in Safari.  I believe (please tell me if this not correct) that [intellipoint](http://macappstore.org/microsoft-office/) will unlock this feature.

The instruction's step-1 calls for:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null ; brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask 2> /dev/null
```

Step-1 seems to install brew, however, I am reluctant to execute this command because `brew cask` has already been used to install applications such as sublime-text.

```
brew cask install microsoft-office
```

returns the error:

> Error: Cask 'microsoft-intellipoint' is unavailable: No Cask with this
> name exists.

Per the [comments](http://macappstore.org/microsoft-office/) I tried:

```
brew cask install caskroom/drivers/microsoft-intellipoint
```

Which returned:

> Error: caskroom/drivers was moved. Tap homebrew/cask-drivers instead.

Is there a method to determine the cause of the error without performing Step-1?  I am concerned that Step-1 may cause problems as brew is already installed per https://brew.sh  If the fix is to perform Step-1 because it somehow adds the equivalent of a repository, I would appreciate an ELI5

Based on this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250707651) I would like to avoid disabling the System Integrity Protection for the very old Microsoft Drivers.

I suspect the side-buttons are sending a signal and it may be possible to configure OS X per the goal.

Answer (score 1):

[SensibleSideButtons](https://sensible-side-buttons.archagon.net) might help with your problem, but keep in mind it is a third-party solution, so there is a chance it won't work properly.